# What Windows event fires when you un-hide a form?

Tags: windows, winforms

For various reasons, I've got a form in an app that needs to remain opened all the time (mostly because users want any data they type there to be "remembered" by the form)... so I allow them to hide it only.

I had THOUGHT that adding a "shown" event would allow me to fire some code every time they re-displayed the form, but now I see that the Shown event only fires ONCE during the form's lifecycle.

What event fires when you do another "Show()" on the hidden form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the VisibleChanged event
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visiblechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yep, looks like this fires before the "Shown" event and yet will fire after I hide and re-show the form as well.  Just what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need the Activated event.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Actually you probably need the answer from Hans Passant.His event best suits the need you described.Activated is called even if you open another window and go back to your form(While it is still visible).I don't know if you need this.

Comment: Activated appears to have done the trick!  Thank you!  Oh, just now saw your second reply.   Well, this form is actually a child form from the main application (form).  Users like to keep it opened all the time (it's for sending out pages to employee cell phones).  So, if this fires whenever they click away and click back... hmmm... not sure if that'd be overkill or desirable.  I'll have to think about that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

VisibleChanged event :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visiblechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Activated event :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated(v=vs.110).aspx
[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated(v=vs.110).aspx)